# SQL Server 2005 Date Formatting [DD-Mon-YY hh:mm:ss]

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime

I have datetimes stored in a table in SQL Server 2005 in the format of:

```
 2012-04-16 00:00:00.000
```

I need to get date in the format of 16-Apr-2012 00:00:00 in my query result.

What is the best method of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Select Convert(VarChar(20),[SomeDate],113)
```

113, is 24h format and includes millisecond, the varchar(20) chops them off.

For further reference one of my favourite MSDN pages [T-SQL Convert DateTime To String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: And `STUFF(STUFF(CONVERT(...),3,1,'-'),7,1,'-')` to complete the resemblance.

Comment: I missed the hyphens. Are they important. :)

Comment: Have no idea. Hopefully they aren't, as without them the solution is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

> When you are trying to read the date, just convert it to the format you need.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 113)
```

> [List of SQL Date formats.](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Comment: No seconds in that one mate.